Issues with File Upload in ASP.NET Core using Blazor
I'm working on a project with separate backend and frontend folders. On the frontend side, I have the following service for uploading files:
 public async Task<IEnumerable<FileMetaDataDto>> UploadFileAsync(IList<IBrowserFile> files, Guid projectId, Guid? commentId)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "files",
            FileName = file.Name,
        };
        
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

        content.Add(fileContent);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Check-3 {projectId}, Comment ID: {commentId}, Content: {content}");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"api/Files/project/{projectId}/upload-multiple?commentId={commentId}", content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<FileMetaDataDto>>();
}

On the backend side, my controller looks like this:
    [HttpPost("project/{projectId}/upload-multiple")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadMultiple(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, Guid projectId, [FromQuery] Guid? commentId)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check server side");
    var results = await _fileService.UploadMultipleFilesAsync(files, projectId, commentId);

    return Ok(results);
}

When I try to upload files, I get an error after the console log Console.WriteLine($"Check-3 {projectId}, Comment ID: {commentId}, Content: {content}"):

An error occurred while sending the request.

Additionally, I don't see the console log from the server side  Console.WriteLine("Check server side");.
When I attempt to add multiple files, I receive the following error:

Error: There is no file with ID 1. The file list may have changed. See https://aka.ms/aspnet/blazor-input-file-multiple-selections.
Error: There is no file with ID 1. The file list may have changed. See https://aka.ms/aspnet/blazor-input-file-multiple-selections.
at Ze (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:36968)
at Object.readFileData (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:36894)
at https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3244
at new Promise ()
at y.beginInvokeJSFromDotNet (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3201)
at Yt._invokeClientMethod (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:60713)
at Yt._processIncomingData (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:58188)
at Yt.connection.onreceive (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:51829)
at s.onmessage (https://localhost:55327/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:79974)

The other endpoints in my project are working correctly.
I have verified the URLs and endpoints to ensure they match.
I'm using Blazor Server for the frontend.
       public async Task<List<FileMetadataDto>> UploadMultipleFilesAsync(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, Guid projectId, Guid? commentId)
    {
        var responses = new List<FileMetadataDto>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileMetadataDto response = await UploadFileAsync(file, projectId, commentId);
            
            responses.Add(response);
        }

        return responses;
    }


What is the Filename : FileName = file.Name,

@jdweng  the file.Name represents the name of the file that is being uploaded from the user's device. This is typically the original name of the file as it exists on the user's filesystem. The FileName property is set to this value to inform the server of the original file name.

You posted UploadMultiple not UploadMultipleFilesAsync.  You are making an http  connection with MIME attachments (MultipartFormDataContent) which is one request and the body of the request contains more than one file.  The error looks like it is in UploadMultipleFilesAsync which is not posted.

@jdweng the server-side Console.WriteLine("Check server side"); is not being executed, it means the request is either not reaching the backend or there is an issue with the request handling.I am posted UploadMultipleFilesAsync.

The server upload multiple expects one MIME request with multiple attachments.  Your client upload multiple is sending one request with a single attachment.  This line should be after the foreach : FileMetadataDto response = await UploadFileAsync(file, projectId, commentId);

I am having an issue uploading multiple images with Blazor Server; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78816542/blazor-server-net-8-multiple-image-upload-problem
